# Как сохранить данные при закрытии страницы или браузера!

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Есть такое событие

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e.returnValue = "";
};
```

При закрытие вкладки или браузера выплывает такое окно,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как передать свою функцию сохранения данных по нажатию на копку закрыть?

Comment: localStorage, sessionStorage

Comment: Ну то есть, так как я хочу сделать нельзя? Только в localStorage сохранять?

Comment: Многие браузеры не позволяют даже своё сообщение в это окно передавать, поэтому сомневаюсь, что вы сможете перехватить результат этого `prompt`'a.

Comment: понял, спасибо.